# Prepend information to jenkins test result link

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We use Jenkins to run our nightly test builds, regression, navigation tests, etc. In our python scripts, we have an `__author__ = 'Name of author'`. I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to be able to prepend that author and value to the test results link? [image]

So in the image above the I would like to have it say `src.tests.smoke.test_gl_smoke_author_name of author`

Is this something which is possible? Is there a plugin which handles this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the link names are generated from the path to the tests.

If you have sufficient privileges, as part of the Jenkins build, you can create a symlink with the author's name and have it point to you src directory. Then point Jenkins at the symlink.

Sample Script:

```
#In same directory as src
ln -s src nameOfAuthor
```

If you don't want to do that, you can create a temporary directory with the author's name and copy all the tests into it, then point Jenkins to where the tests were copied to.

Sample Script:

```
#In same directory as src
mkdir nameOfAuthor
cp -r src nameOfAuthor/src
```

Comment: where would I put that first script? Would that simply go into the shell script I am already executing as part of our builds?

Comment: Yes. Do it just before you have Jenkins execute the tests.

Comment: I am getting an error that it fails to create the symbolic link. `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘nameOfAuthor’: File exists`

Comment: Well is there another file in that directory called 'nameOfAuthor'? Also solution 2 should work just as well if you can't get the link to work.